# Unsigned char value cycle C++

Tags: c++, types, casting, char

I (think I) understand how the maths with different variable types works. For example, if I go over the max limit of an `unsigned int` variable, it will loop back to `0`.

I don't understand the behavior of this code with `unsigned char`:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char var{ 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < 501; ++i) {
        var += 1;
        std::cout << var << '\n';
    }
}
```

This just outputs `1...9`, then some symbols and capital letters, and then it just doesn't print anything. It doesn't loop back to the values `1...9` etc.

On the other hand, if I cast to `int` before printing:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char var{ 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < 501; ++i) {
        var += 1;
        std::cout << (int)var << '\n';
    }
}
```

It does print from `1...255` and then loops back from `0...255`.

Why is that? It seems that the `unsgined char` variable **does** loop (as we can see from the int cast).

Is it safe to to maths with `unsigned char` variables? What is the behavior that I see here?

Comment: What compiler is compiling this, and what command line are you using to run it? The non-repeating behavior of 1..9 may be due to how the shell you're using deals with specific non-printable characters (and not a C++ thing).

Comment: @JohnFilleau I am using `g++ (GCC) 11.1.0` as `g++ test.cpp -o test`. And just running as `./test`

Comment: Do you see something different? e.g. the repeating 1..9?

Comment: I see the repeating 1..9, along with non-printable standins before and after the ASCII set. But the 1..9 definitely repeats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why doesn't it print the expected integer value?

The issue is not with the looping of `char`. The issue is with the insertion operation for `std::ostream` objects and 8-bit integer types. The non-member `operator<<` functions for these types treat all 8-bit integers (`char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`) as their ASCII character types.

[operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)

The canonical way to handle outputing 8-bit integer types is the way you're doing it. I personally prefer this instead:

```
char foo;
std::cout << +foo;
```

The unary `+` operator promotes the `char` type to an `integer` type, which then causes the integer printing function to be called.

Note that integer overflow is only defined for `unsigned` integer types. If you repeat this with `char` or `signed char`, the behavior is undefined by the standard. SOMETHING will happen, for sure, because we live in reality, but that overflow behavior may differ from compiler to compiler.

### Why doesn't it repeat the 0..9 characters

I tested this using `g++` to compile, and bash on Ubuntu 20.04. My non-printable characters are handled as explicit symbols in some cases, or nothing printed in other cases. The non-repeating behavior must be due to how your shell handles these non-printable characters. We can't answer that without more information.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned chars aren't trated as numbers in this case. This data type is literally a byte:

```
1 byte = 8 bits = 0000 0000 which means 0.
```

What cout is printing is the character that represents that byte you changed by adding +1 to it.

For example:

```
0 = 0000 0000
1 = 0000 0001
2 = 0000 0010
.
.
.
9 = 0000 1001
```

Then, here start other chars that arent related to numbers.
So, if you cast it to int, it will give you the numeric representations of that byte, giving you a 0-255 output.

Hope this clarifies!

Edit: Made the explanation more clear.

Comment: *"Unsigned chars aren't numbers"* They are. It's just that `cout` treats them unusually.

Comment: [`unsigned char` is an integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I meant they aren't treated as numbers in this case, but yea, i didn't express myself properly.